# Stick div to top on scroll and unstick later

Tags: javascript, sticky

Currently when a div hits the top of the browser it becomes sticky (fixed) and that works perfect. What I would like is the div to unstick again after continue scrolling for another 500 pixels.

Is there a way to do this?

*ps. I know the Stickem solution but that is a lot if Javascript, I have the feeling that this can be done much easier.*

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var header = document.getElementById("center");
var sticky = header.offsetTop-10;
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#top { height:200px; background:#BFBDC1; }
#center { height:30px; background:#37323E; }
#bottom { height:4000px; background:#6D6A75; }

.sticky { position:fixed; top:0px; width:100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding an upper bound to your if condition should do the trick.

Instead of just checking if the current offset is greater than the lower bound (`sticky` in this case), also check if it is less than the desired upper bound (`sticky + 500`).

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var header = document.getElementById("center");
var sticky = header.offsetTop-10;
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky && window.pageYOffset < sticky + 500) { // <--here
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#top { height:200px; background:#BFBDC1; }
#center { height:30px; background:#37323E; }
#bottom { height:4000px; background:#6D6A75; }

.sticky { position:fixed; top:0px; width:100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right track, thanks but after 500px it now suddenly disappears, is it possible to scroll it out smoothly?

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren If you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery's [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Add some additional conditional in your function testing against window.scrollY